Does the jazz term 'head' refer to both instrumental and vocal themes?
For some reason I associate the term 'head' with bebop era and elaborate instrumental melodies, not with songs with lyrics.  Does it sound natural to 'play the head' of a Tin Pan Alley song (which would imply a singer actually singing the words)?  Does the term 'head' have any semantic, stylistic or historical restrictions, like the one I'm referring to?  (Is it all in my head?  Ok, I'll see myself out...)

The line between instrumental and vocal jazz blurs with jazz pieces that only sometimes have lyrics such as "Sing, Sing, Sing".

The term 'head'  refers to the first time through a jazz number, where the melody is stated (fairly) verbatim. Many jazz standards ARE 'Tin pan alley' songs.  I don't think 'head' is disallowed in those cases!
If it's a vocal piece, we might say 'she sings the head'. The implication is that it will be followed by several improvised choruses, vocal or instrumental.
The classical equivalent would be a set of variations, where it would be called the 'theme'.

A perhaps closer classical equivalent is the baroque aria, where "from the head" is da capo.

@phoog 'Head' as a literal translation of 'capo' is a red herring here, I think.  There's an obvious connection with the jazz meaning, but only a superficial one.

I don't think it's a translation.  It's semantically the same concept: the thing that comes first is the head.  (Similarly, the thing that comes last is the tail, which in Italian is coda.)

@phoog the theme doesn't necessary come at the very beginning, it may be e.g. preceded by some introduction

Isn't the head sometimes a riff based theme, usually "written out" without improv. then the improv. choruses that follow are sometimes based on chord progressions not used in the head?

In my experience the word “head” is used much more in instrumental settings than when there is a vocalist. Of course if you were to use it on a gig that has a singer it would be clearly understood. Its use, although common for bebop is not limited to that. It can also apply to American songbook songs, modern jazz or any music that is played in a jazz setting where a melody (head) is played followed by solos based on the form and concluding with an “out head”.

About the vocal/instrumental difference, could part of the distinction be vocalist as the featured performer, instrumental solos as interlude, and the sung song is not a "head" but the main point, compared to all instrumental bands where the soloists are the featured  performers and the "head" acts as intro/coda?

@MichaelCurtis That is an excellent observation Michael, in a large percentage of situations with a vocalist I would say that’s the case.
